# Definition of $\varepsilon$-regular pair

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The below is the definition of $\varepsilon$-regular pair which is important notion in Szemeredi regularity lemma.

> **Definition** ($\varepsilon$-regular pair)
>
> Let $G$ be a graph and $U,W\subseteq V(G)$. We call $(U,W)$ an
> $\varepsilon$-***regular pair*** in $G$ if for all $A\subseteq U$ and
> $B\subseteq W$ with $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon
>  |W|$, one has  $$|d(A,B)-d(U,W)|\leq \varepsilon.$$ If $(U,W)$ is not
> $\varepsilon$-regular, then we say that their irregularity is
> witnessed by some $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq W$ satisfying
> $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$, $|B|\geq \varepsilon |W|$, and
> $|d(A,B)-d(U,W)|> \varepsilon.$

*Remark:* We need the hypotheses $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon |W|$ since the definition would be too restrictive otherwise. For example, by taking $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{y\}$, $d(A,B)$ could end up being both $0$ (if $xy\notin E$) and $1$ (if $xy\in E$).

I really did not understand the meaning of the above remark? What is wrong if we omit these inequalities (I mean $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon |W|$)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the remark: if we did not have that condition, then it would require that for any $x \in U$ and $y \in W$,
$$
    |d(\{x\}, \{y\}) - d(U,W)| \le \varepsilon.
$$
In particular, when $xy$ is any *edge* between $U$ and $W$, this condition implies $|1 - d(U,W)| \le \varepsilon$, so $d(U,W) \ge 1-\varepsilon$; on the other hand, when $xy$ is *not* an edge, this condition implies that $|0 - d(U,W)| \le \varepsilon$, so $d(U,W) \le \varepsilon$.

In any interesting scenario, there will be both edges and non-edges between $U$ and $W$, and $\varepsilon$ will be less than $\frac12$, and under those circumstances no pair $(U,W)$ would satisfy the condition above.

We would like the definition of $\varepsilon$-regular pair to be inclusive enough that **it's possible for $\varepsilon$-regular pairs to exist** and so we need to add the condition that $|A| \ge \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B| \ge \varepsilon |W|$ to address this scenario.

---

More carefully, we might ask: why is the condition $|A| \ge \varepsilon |U|$ and not $|A| \ge 100$ or $|A| \ge \frac1{\varepsilon}$ or $|A| \ge \varepsilon |U|^{1/2}$? Here, it's less clear, and the definition we have was made by reasoning along the following lines:

- It's something that the regularity lemma is strong enough to guarantee;
- In turn, the definition itself is strong enough to have the consequences we want it to have;
- Also, $\varepsilon$-regular-pairs are motivated by the edges between $U$ and $W$ "behaving like the edges in a random graph", however informally - so we would not want to make the definition so strong that actual random graphs don't satisfy it.

Comment: Ok! Assume that we omit the condition "$|A|\geq \varepsilon|U|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon |W|$". In that case we say that the pair $(U,W)$ is $\varepsilon$-***regular***, if $1-\varepsilon\leq d(U,W)\leq \varepsilon$ provided that there are edges and nonedges between $U$ and $W$. And we see that such pair does not exist if $\varepsilon <1/2$.

Comment: 1) I still cannot get what is wrong with that new modified definition?
2) Also you said that "We would like the definition of $\varepsilon$-regular pair to be inclusive enough that **it's possible for $\varepsilon$-regular pairs to exist** and so we need to add the condition that $|A| \ge \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B| \ge \varepsilon |W|$ to address this scenario." I also did not understand that.

Comment: The point is: what good is a definition if nothing can satisfy it? We are free to define a "strict $\varepsilon$-regular pair" to be the version where the condition $|A| \ge \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B| \ge \varepsilon |W|$ is omitted. There's no *contradiction* within that definition. But then we won't encounter any strict $\varepsilon$-regular pairs to talk about, and in that case, why did we bother defining them?

Comment: Makes sense! +1

Comment: Just want to clarify one moment: In the definition of $\varepsilon$-regular pair do we impose any restriction on $\varepsilon$? Smth like $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$?

Comment: We might as well. (That's a similar situation actually: nothing goes wrong or explodes if $\varepsilon$ is outside that range, but the result is not useful. In practice, proofs that use regularity will have stricter upper bounds on $\varepsilon$, based on how that regularity gets used; one might write something like "apply the regularity lemma with some $\varepsilon < \frac1{100}$".)

Comment: But in all the sources which I've seen I saw that $\varepsilon>0$ and that is all.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you mention that as part of your definition or not. When you write basically any proof that uses the regularity lemma, it will require some upper bound on $\varepsilon$ in order to succeed.

Comment: In the definition of $\varepsilon$-regular pair $(X,Y)$ what if one of the sets is empty? In that case $d(X,Y)$ is not defined at all.

Comment: I think you're asking several questions about technical points of the definition in settings where it's not meant to be used and has unexpected behavior, but this is not helpful to understanding regularity as is typically used. We do not run into situations in which $X$ or $Y$ is empty.

Comment: Hi Misha! Of course, you are right because in regularity lemma you will be dealing with partition of the vertex set (which by definition should has nonempty parts). I was just clarifying! Thank you for all your help! Appreciate it! I think I am done with this topic